# useContentSize set to undefined after setMinimumSize

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, window, chromium

For some reason `setMinimumSize` sets `useContentSize` to `undefined`. It also does not enlarge the window to the minimum size if the window is smaller than the minimum size.

```
const { remote } = require('electron')
remote.getCurrentWindow().setMinimumSize(X, Y)

// Here is a rough solution to the second problem.
let width, height
width = innerWidth < X ? X : innerWidth
height = innerHeight < Y ? Y : innerHeight
remote.getCurrentWindow().setContentSize(width, height)
```

Does anybody know how to fix the `useContentSize` problem?

[Here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21740) is the link to the bug report on GitHub.